# DB2 SQL - Select all values of a table related to another table

Tags: sql, join, db2

Maybe I'm not clear on the topic for what I'm trying to ask, so here is my question:

I have three tables for now, say, `User`, `User Role`, `Role`, which make reference to each other:

```
User
========
USER_ID | USER_NAME 
1       | User A
2       | User B

User Role
========
USER_ID | ROLE_ID
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1

Role
========
ROLE_ID | ROLE_NAME
1       | Admin
2       | Supervisor
```

As you can see, `User A` has two role for now: `Admin` and `Supervisor`
What I'm trying to do now is selecting all users with role `Admin`, then the sql result should display all other roles related to that user also.

Say, the sql is executed like this: 
`select A.*, C.ROLE_NAME from User A, User Role B, Role C where A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID and B.ROLE_ID = C.ROLE_ID and B.ROLE_ID = '1'`

The above sql should only display `User A` with only one role, `Admin`:

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | ROLE_NAME
1       | User A    | Admin
2       | User B    | Admin
```

But what I want is, beside `Admin`, the sql result should also display `User A` with `ROLE_NAME` = `Supervisor`:

```
USER_ID | USER_NAME | ROLE_NAME
1       | User A    | Admin
1       | User A    | Supervisor
2       | User B    | Admin
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
with ur as (
      select u.*, C.ROLE_NAME
      from User u join
           User_Role ur
           on u.user_id = ur.user_id join
           Role r 
           on r.role_id = ur.role_id
     )
select ur.*
from ur
where exists (select 1
              from ur ur2
              where ur2.user_id = ur.user_id and ur2.role_name = 'admin'
             );
```

Also, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax with the condition in the `ON` clause.

Second, use meaningful table aliases rather than arbitrary letters such as "a", "b", and "c".

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! Am using meaningful alias in my program, but the context is simplified here so as to make the question look clean ;)